# four-square sum representation for integers upto N

Tags: algorithm, number-theory

[Lagrange's four-square theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange's_four-square_theorem) proves that any natural number can be written as the sum of four square numbers. What I need is to find any one way to write a natural number `x` as sum of four square numbers for all `0 <= x <= N` for any given upper limit `N`.

What I have done so far is find two-square sum representation for all the numbers `<= N` for which it is possible to find one, and saved them in an array called `two_square_div`. Then I used a greedy approach like following:

```
last_two_square_sum = 0

for num in 0..N
    if num can be written as sum of two square
        last_two_square_sum = num
    other_last_two_square_sum = num - last_two_square_sum
    four_square_div[num] = (two_square_div[last_two_square_sum], two_square_div[other_last_two_square_sum]
```

But this approach does not work for numbers like 23, for which `last_two_square_sum = 20` `other_last_two_square_sum = 3`. But 3 can not be written as sum of two squares so this method fails.

So could anybody provide a correct `O(N)` solution or any helpful hint? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithm should make more than one attempt (if it already does, then the exit condition must be improved).

23 can be written as 3 + 20, yes; but 3 is not a decomposable of order two and can't lead to a solution.

So **you go on**: next you try 4 + 19, and this time it's 19 that is rejected. Next you try 5, so 23-5 is 18, and 5 is 1<sup>2</sup> + 2<sup>2</sup> while 18 is 3<sup>2</sup> + 3<sup>2</sup>.

(Of course this is not O(N) at all).

It is not clear to me how you arrive at 20 and not accept previous solutions; try posting the whole of the code.

Also, try asking on Math StackExchange.